# Apache - Limitations of logically linking RewriteCond in 2.2/2.4

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, logical-operators

These days I read a [very interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922399/how-to-use-and-or-for-rewritecond-on-apache) about the precedence of `[OR]` over the implicit `[AND]`. I really liked the original question as well as highly appreciated answer.

I just recently stumbled upon further problems concerning this topic.

The problems start as soon as you try to express the following:

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteCond C
RewriteRule ...
```

**with `A OR (B AND C)`. Where ever you place the `[OR]`, it won't work:**

```
#resolves to (A OR B) AND C
RewriteCond A [OR]
RewriteCond B
RewriteCond C
RewriteRule ...

#resolves to A AND (B OR C)
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B [OR]
RewriteCond C
RewriteRule ...

#makes no sense at all with no further cond after c
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteCond C [OR]
RewriteRule ...
```

It doesn't get better with more RewriteCon, since you'll always need a 'partner' to pair the [OR] with :(
My finding was that

**You can only express RewriteCond-sets that come from the CNF ([conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)).**

Which, imho, is pretty huge and caused by the **lack of an explicit `[AND]`** as well as **no possiblity to bracket two Cond together.**

**PLEEEEASE** correct me if I'm wrong, I really hope that I just missed something! Not that you can always code more than one rule to satisfy your needs, but this has really been bugging me, since I had a real user-case where that was needed.

---

**TL;DR**

The second you try to express

```
(block of 'n' ANDs) OR X
# with n > 0
# and X being a random logical expression (or in rewrite-terms: Rewrite-Cond set)
```

you just **can't** with current set of logical operators (`[OR]`,`!`)